# Bootstrap navbar lag when closing toggler

Tags: javascript, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, lag

I created a bootstrap navbar for my Wordpress site and am having an issue. The navbar works, but when the user closes the expanded navbar, the li items linger and lag for awhile before disappearing. I would like them to disappear with the rest of the navbar background but can't figure out what is causing the delay and how to edit it. Is this a built in bootstrap feature? This issue only happens when the user is at the top of the page (when the user scrolls, the background changes to a white background color, which makes the lag less noticeable (although still present).

Here is the draft site: http://xbm.naa.mybluehost.me/

Thank you!!

Comment: Can you re-create the issue here on StackOverflow via the snippet feature. A reduced example helps make it easier to see what is wrong.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You need to present your question _here_.

Comment: Hint: If you find that difficult it's probable because you have some custom or theme CSS that's messing with Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was:

```
.collapsing{
    transition: none;
}
```

The transition effect wasn't being applied to the navbar links, just the background color.